# How to make an Outlook rule that looks to see whether I got an email as a part of a group?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, email-filter

We have a lot of email groups defined at work.  And my name is in a lot of them.

How can I create a rule that checks to see whether the email arrived as a result of me being in a group?  If that is the case, I'd like to move it to some other folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may depend on the Exchange settings. Our server does not expand distribution lists and this solution works for me.

I have another rule that email with the condition 'sent only to me' to another folder.
There are some other rules based on a senders.

Every email that includes my address (i.e. someone added my address to the To or Cc) goes to separate folder. 
Any emails that are sent to a Distribution list that I am part of stay in Inbox or is subject to other rules.

Outlook has additional condition 'where my name is not in the To box' that could be used to move email to other folder. But that will move emails CCed to you (and not to a group).

Comment: Can you help me with specific settings that you use to differentiate mails where you are the only recepient vs mails where you are in to with others.

Answer (score 0):

You can't really do that since as soon as an e-mail is sent the group would be resolved to the individual members and then delivered to them. You can't tell what groups, if any, were used to add the addresses to an email.

You can do rules which check if you are on the To line or CC, and if you are the only one there, but this won't distinguish between emails sent to you and a couple more people or a huge group.